# Merge [custom-application] and [third-party-software]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [[custom-application]](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-application) and [[third-party-software]](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/third-party-software) currently have similar descriptions. Based on this the tags should be merged.

**[custom-application]**:

> A third party application that works in tandem with SharePoint to accomplish a specific task.

**[third-party-software]**:

> Third party software are additions to SharePoint that are sold by some other company than Microsoft. Tag questions with this when it's possible the problem or solution is related to the customization installed by the third party software.

I understand there's a slight difference between the meanings, as one points to applications and other to software. Therefore maybe just the descriptions could be extended to distinguish the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Therefore maybe just the descriptions could be extended to distinguish the tags?

I think this is a much better idea, than merging two completely different tags. The keyword here is **sold** where we think of companies like Nintex, Metalogics, K2, ShareGate and other 3rd party software companies. To me custom application is a specific application in a specific farm developed by people like us, and where the intention of the custom application is never to sell it somewhere else.

That's a big difference where you on the one hand (3rd party) have an external support organisation to communicate with, but on the other hand (custom app) are left with source code and instructions from the developing team.

Comment: I agree with this. The custom application is clear term for people familiar with SharePoint whereas third party software has a more universal meaning. The meaning "developed by people like us" is something I'd like to see on the description, as that's what it basically is about.

Comment: @moe You can suggest that edit in the tag wiki, and if approved you'll get 2 point for the effort :)

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm afraid I can't come with a solid, unambiguous and yet a brief explanation. Therefore it would be just the best for all if someone with a good idea does it for us.

Comment: @Moe The good part of a tag **wiki** is that you can start to edit and make your best explanation, and the reviewer can add/change your post to something better. So if you put your mind to it I'm confident you'll do a good job that will contribute to the tag wiki as a whole. We are all here to learn, and why not start by a tag wiki edit :-)